# Getting my head around implementations

Tags: java, interface

I have an interface`FileService`
And an implementation of it `FileServiceBean`

I want to be able to process multiple filetypes.

e.g. `fileService.processFile(FileDescriptor);`

Where, the fileDescriptor is a class e.g.

```
public class FileDescriptor {
@Column(name = "FILE_TYPE")
protected String fileType;
```

}

Then I want multiple extensions of the FileServiceBean to process different filetypes.  And FileServiceBean would have all the methods common to all filetypes.

e.g.

```
PhotoProcessingBean extends FileProcessingBean
VideoProcessingBean extends FileProcesingBean
```

How do I make the interface decide what implementation to use?  I am rather new to this and not really quite sure how to ask the question to search google for the answer.

Ideally it would not just accept FileDescriptor.  e.g. It could be something else like just File.

```
fileService.processFile(Object);
```

Comment: what kind of `FileDescriptor` do you have?

Comment: It sounds like you don't need a FileDescriptor at all as each concrete bean will process a specific file type. Also, interfaces don't decide on what implementation to use. An interface is just a contract of what methods that your implementations must implement.

Comment: The interface does not decide anything. You create an object, say with `new PhotoProcessingBean()` and it happens to implement the interface. You are probably looking for a factory pattern where the factory would instanciate the correct object based on the file type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in the end you have to put the decision logic *somewhere*, the only question is *where*?

I think this is a classic application of the factory-pattern: you create an object (the "factory") which has the sole purpose of deciding which concrete implemenation of a common interface to create for a given case. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

Along the lines of:

```
PhotoProcessingBean extends FileProcessingBean {...}
VideoProcessingBean extends FileProcesingBean {...}

class FileProcessingFactory {
    public static FileService createFileService(FileDescriptor descriptor) {
        switch(descriptor.getFileType()) {
            case 'Photo': return new PhotoProcessingBean();
            case 'Video': return new VideoProcessingBean();
            default: // do some error handling
        }
    }
}
```

And using it:

```
for(FileDescriptor descriptor : /* wherever they come from */) {
    FileService processor = FileProcessingFactory.createFileService(descriptor);
    processor.processFile(descriptor);
}
```

Sure enough you can also soften up the interface by accepting objects instead of file descriptors. This depends on the concrete application.

Comment: This makes sense.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an interface:

```
public interface IFileService{
    void processFile();
}
```

And the FileProcessingBean class that implements this:

```
public class FileProcessingBean implements IFileService{

    //other code here

    @Override
    public void processFile(){
        //add code for implementation of method
    }
}
```

If you have two other classes that extend FileProcessingBean:

```
public class PhotoProcessingBean extends FileProcessingBean{
    @Override
    public void processFile(){
        System.out.println("Processing PHOTO...");
    }
}


public class VideoProcessingBean extends FileProcessingBean{
    @Override
    public void processFile(){
        System.out.println("Processing VIDEO...");
    }
}
```

If you would like to use it:

```
//This is an OOP concept called Polymorphism:
IFileService photoProcess = new PhotoProcessingBean();
IFileService videoProcess = new VideoProcessingBean();
```

Calling `photoProcess.processFile();` and `videoProcess.processFile()` would yield different the implementations:

```
photoProcess.processFile();
videoProcess.processFile();
```

And you'll get the following output:

```
Processing PHOTO...
Processing VIDEO...
```

Regarding your point about not just accepting FileDescriptor but also 'something else', my recommendation would be to either know exactly what sort of arguments you are expecting, and then either implementing overriding methods or via an interface. It would not be wise to use Object as a method argument as Object is a superclass from which all objects are descendants of. You would essentially be opening the 'floodgates' and potentially run into runtime errors.